# An attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I got this error after using maven command

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:5.1.3:izpack 
(default) on project izpack-example: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:5.1.3:izpack failed: For artifact {com.example.test.installer:izpack-example:1.0-SNAPSHOT:jar}: An attached artifact 
must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact. -> [Help 1]

I tried searching for solution, there must be something wrong with dependencies (as the error said), but still can't figure it out.

Here are my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.test.installer</groupId>
<artifactId>izpack-example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>An Example of an installer using izpack</name>

<!-- seems like this needs to be "jar" to accomplish a build of java code too? a bit confused
on the difference between putting "pom" and "jar" here. -->
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<!-- maven repository where the izpack-maven-plugin  and such live -->
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>codehaus-releases</id>
  <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <staging.dir>${project.build.directory}/staging</staging.dir>
 <izpack.version>5.1.3</izpack.version>
</properties>

<!-- must have a dependency on our separate package that contains the custom
panels -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.example.test.installer</groupId>
   <artifactId>izpack-panels</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>

<defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>

<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
      <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${izpack.version}</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>


<plugins>

  <!-- copy all resources to the staging directory. -->
  <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- here the phase you need -->
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${staging.dir}</outputDirectory>
          <!-- recursive copy of all resource under src/main/izpack. this is the stuff to install as well as install.xml and panel data and such -->
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/izpack</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


  <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
         <execution>
           <!-- copy izpack custom (custom panels, etc.) jars to izpack staging custom -->
           <id>copy-izpack-dependencies</id>
           <phase>prepare-package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${staging.dir}/custom</outputDirectory>
              <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
              <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
              <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              <includeArtifactIds>izpack-panels</includeArtifactIds> <!-- IMPORTANT: this causes *only* our custom panels to be copied -->
           </configuration>
        </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>

<!--
 We need to tell the izpack-maven-plugin what to use as the base directory (this is our staging area), and also tell it the install file to use:
-->
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
   <artifactId>izpack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <!-- <version>${izpack.version}</version> -->
   <configuration>
      <descriptorEncoding>UTF-8</descriptorEncoding>
    </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals><goal>izpack</goal></goals>
         <configuration>
            <!-- base for relative paths in izpack descriptor -->
            <baseDir>${staging.dir}</baseDir>
            <installFile>${staging.dir}/install.xml</installFile>
             <output>${project.build.directory}/${outname}</output>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <!-- must have a dependency here on any code used in the installer, otherwise the classloader
   will not find it.  So in this case we need our panels and then the package that contains the base classes
   for the panels -->
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
        <artifactId>izpack-panel</artifactId>
        <version>${izpack.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.test.installer</groupId>
        <artifactId>izpack-panels</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem with izpack 5.1.3 , reverted back to 5.1.2 and the error is gone. I had `finalName` defined in both cases.

EDIT: izpack 5.1.3 works, but as suggested by @Prim you need to have both `finalName` and `classifier` in the configuration.

Comment: I go with this at last. Just want the error to go away, 5.1.2 is safe for now :)

Comment: Version 5.1.2 fails when running the installation on Java >= 9 with [IZPACK-1588](https://izpack.atlassian.net/browse/IZPACK-1588). We are stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're calling the `izpack-maven-plugin` which is currently trying to produce an artefact which has the same name that one another artefact (the main one)

To fix that, you should use `finalName` or `classifier` fields to configure this plugin.

See the document here: https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/491628/IzPack+Maven+Plugin+Reference

Comment: I tried add those as your suggested by include this code inside <configuration> tag of izpack-maven-plugin, but still get the same error message
      <finalName>${outname}</finalName>
      <enableOverrideArtifact>true</enableOverrideArtifact>
      <mkdirs>true</mkdirs>
      <autoIncludeUrl>false</autoIncludeUrl>
      <autoIncludeDevelopers>false</autoIncludeDevelopers>

Comment: What is the value of  `outname` ? did you try to set `finalName` to an unique value which doesn't exist ? You can also set a `classifier` to be sure that your artefact is unique (the classifier value will be used as a suffix of main artefact name)

Comment: Currently my outname value is **izpack-example-custom-me** Very unique and doesn't exist for sure. Do I need to make it relevant with others?

Comment: Actually, changing `classifier` finally helped, changing `finalName` didn't.